# How to find a site whose name I do not remember in Chrome history?

Tags: google-chrome, web-browser, browser-history

I need to find a specific site in my Chrome history, but I don't remember the name of the site.
My Chrome history is full of Youtube and Google searches so I can't just scroll before I find the site that I need. Maybe I can somehow exclude Youtube and Google searches in my Chrome history in order to find the site that I need? Please help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome stores its history in an SQLite database in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1` by default. You could run

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ 1
sqlite3 History
```

to open it, and then use a query like

```
select title, url from urls where url not like '%youtube.com/%' and url not like '%google.com/%';
```

to list all URL not matching the pattern.

If there are a lot of lines to search through, you can also dump the content of that table into a CSV file.

```
sqlite3 -csv History "select title, url from urls where url not like '%youtube.com/%' and url not like '%google.com/%'" > ~/Desktop/URLs.csv
```

will create a CSV file containing page titles and URLs on your desktop from where you can open it in Numbers, LibreOffice or any text editor.